# RMI loopback: Same thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

If a thread `jack` on host A calls an RMI method `foo` on host B, and in that method host B calls a method `bar` on host A, will `bar` be executed by thread `jack`?

I assume it will be another thread, but I think it might be possible in theory.

Why somebody would want it? Lock reentrancy, for one, would be a convenient feature.

Comment: It is possible in theory, but I don't believe it works that way in practice. Each RMI client has its own thread(s) on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: this will be a **different** thread for sure.

Long one: think about it. When `jack @ A` host calls `foo() @ B` host, the `jack @ A` thread is blocked waiting for `foo()` response. So when `foo() @ B` calls `bar() @ A` the `jack @ A` is guaranteed to be still waiting, hence there is no way that `bar()` will be handled by it.

Also note that there is a separate thread pool for handling RMI client calls on the server side. So most likely your `jack` thread is actually an application thread and RMI has no access to it. Unless calling `foo() @ B` by `jack` thread was also initiated by external RMI call (too many callbacks, *panic*).

Comment: "the jack @ A thread is blocked waiting for foo() response" - It's actually blocked waiting for a `notify`, and when it's notified it could theoretically perform bar if it's told too. That's why I thought it might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

> 3.2    Thread Usage in Remote Method Invocations
>
> A method dispatched by the RMI runtime to a remote object
>   implementation may or may not execute in a separate thread. The RMI
>   runtime makes no guarantees with respect to mapping remote object
>   invocations to threads. Since remote method invocation on the same
>   remote object may execute concurrently, a remote object implementation
>   needs to make sure its implementation is thread-safe.

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch3.html

So, explicitly, that says that the initial calling thread, 'jack', is not specified to be tied to the remote invocation, and as such there can be no guarantee regarding the thread used by the RMI server on 'A' when handling the `bar` call.

And, as Thomasz says, `jack` is blocking already, it would never be able to process the remote invocation from 'B' anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well Threads live inside OS Processes.  So, if you have different JVMs, by definition, they'll be different actual threads.  A thread can only live on a single machine.  But each thread will wait for each RMI call to finish, so it will seem like it's a single thread.

Comment: Yes, but my question is about a single VM calling a method on itself, *through* an external VM.